# Find common elements from given intervals

Tags: c++, range

I am trying to solve this problem where  I need to find common elemets from given Intervals. 
For example in intervals [1,5] ,[2, 8], [3, 4], the common elements from all the intervals would be [3, 4]. 
What is the best way to implement this in C++. I tried to implement it with std::set_intersection. But for that two work, i need to populate an another vector containing elements within the interval, then find the intersection between them  which is not allowed because of space limitation. 
Is there any another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of **N** intervals [x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>], [x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>] ... [x<sub>N</sub>, y<sub>N</sub>] is defined by the range [max(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... , x<sub>N</sub>), min(y<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>, ... , y<sub>N</sub>)]. This can be proved by mathematical induction and takes O(**N**) time. You can read more about interval arithmetic [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic).

**Note**: If we get the final range as [x, y] where x > y, then the range is empty.

Comment: Nice ! This is very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for an [Interval tree.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)

> In computer science, an interval tree is a tree data structure to hold intervals. Specifically, it allows one to efficiently find all intervals that overlap with any given interval or point. It is often used for windowing queries, for instance, to find all roads on a computerized map inside a rectangular viewport, or to find all visible elements inside a three-dimensional scene. A similar data structure is the segment tree.